# Wrapper for a type member

Tags: generics, f#, wrapper

I've been trying to implement a generic function that calls a member of a type. I found that this should be possible by using inline. It didn't help, so I attempted to implement an interface, like this:

```
type Wrappable<'a, 'b> =
    interface
      abstract Wrap : ('b -> 'b) -> 'a
    end

type StateType =
    State of Scene * Cash | Exit
    interface Wrappable<StateType, Scene * Cash> with
        member this.Wrap f =
            match this with
            | Exit -> Exit
            | State (scene, cash) -> f (scene, cash) |> State

let inline wrap f (o:Wrappable<_, _>) = o.Wrap f
```

This works very well, giving the type output

```
type Wrappable<'a,'b> =
  interface
    abstract member Wrap : ('b -> 'b) -> 'a
  end
type StateType =
  | State of Scene * Cash
  | Exit
  with
    interface Wrappable<StateType,(Scene * Cash)>
  end
val inline wrap : f:('a -> 'a) -> o:Wrappable<'b,'a> -> 'b
```

I find this way to be very ugly, though. My question is: is there a better way to wrap a member in a function?

Comment: you are probably looking for [statically resolved type parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) (you can do quite impressive stuff with those) - I just wonder what you are trying to accomplish here - is it just about deciding the right `wrap` by the type of `o`?

Comment: What do you mean by *wrapping a member in a function?* The only member present here is `Wrap`, which (IIUC) you've introduced in order to achieve your goal... So the underlying question, then, is: what's your goal?

Comment: @MarkSeemann It is all about getting the` wrap` function to work with every type that has the member `Wrap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how you can do it using the [*statically resolved type parameters*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) I mentioned:

```
type StateType =
    State of int * string | Exit
        member this.Wrap f =
            match this with
            | Exit -> Exit
            | State (scene, cash) -> f (scene, cash) |> State

let inline wrap f (o : ^a) = (^a : (member Wrap : (^b -> ^b) -> ^a) (o, f))
```

I used `int * string` because I don't know your `Scene` and `Cash` and want to test it:

```
> let x = State (5,"Hallo");;

val x : StateType = State (5,"Hallo")

> let f (x,y) = (x+x,y);;

val f : x:int * y:'a -> int * 'a

> wrap f x;;

val it : StateType = State (10,"Hallo")
```

Comment: Indeed, while the syntax is a bit wonky in my eyes, I think it is still much nicer than fooling around with interfaces. Thank you.

Comment: yeah the syntax is nasty - I basically have to 2-3 WTFs every time I try to do this (is it `(o, f)` or `(o f)`? ... was it `(member ...) (o)` or `(member ... (o))` etc. pp)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an operator? An *implicitly resolved symbolic operator* will be compiled as a static *member constraint invocation expression* anyway, without ugly syntax. That language feature relies on statically resolved type parameters. See 14.2.2 (last row) of the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf).

```
type StateType =
    State of int * string | Exit
    static member ($) (this, f) =
        match this with
        | Exit -> Exit
        | State (scene, cash) -> f (scene, cash) |> State

type UnitType =
    | Etats of float * unit
    static member ($) (Etats (scene, ()), f) =
        f (scene, ()) |> Etats

let inline f (x,y) = (x+x,y)

let st = State (5,"Hallo")
st $ f   // val it : StateType = State (10,"Hallo")

let ut = Etats (5., ())
ut $ f   // val it : UnitType = Etats (10.0,null)
```

Comment: I don't feel comfortable adding unnecessary operators, especially when the function is not to be used with two arguments usually.